# Funktorialität in der Theorie der automorphen Formen

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, langlands-conjectures, reference-request

In 2010 Langlands wrote an article with the title [*Funktorialität in der Theorie der automorphen Formen:  Ihre Entdeckung und ihre Ziele*](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/comments.pdf).  On the IAS website, he says that

> This note ... was written as commentary to accompany the original letter in a collection of documents on reciprocity laws and algebraic number theory, ... to appear.

By the *original letter* he means of course his famous [Letter to André Weil](http://publications.ias.edu/rpl/section/21) in which the Langlands conjectures were first formulated.

**Questions.** Has this collection of documents already appeared?  If not, when and where is it likely to appear?  What other documents does it contain?

Comment: Would you please be kind enough to translate the title for non German speakers?

Comment: Functoriality in the theory of automorphic forms.  *La fonctorialité dans la théorie des formes automorphes*.

Comment: Thank you but actually I understood this part. What I don't understand are the words "Entdeckung" and "Ziele".

Comment: *Entdeckung* = discovery, *découverte* ; *Ziele* = aims, *objectifs*.

Comment: Just for fun I tried an automatic translation: *Funktorialität in the theory of the automorphen forms: Their discovery and their targets*

Answer (score 6):

[Emil Artin and Beyond – Class Field Theory and $L$-Functions](https://www.ems-ph.org/books/book.php?proj_nr=188)

Heritage of European Mathematics

Della Dumbaugh ( University of Richmond, USA )
Joachim Schwermer (University of Vienna, Austria)

Emil Artin and Beyond – Class Field Theory and $L$-Functions

ISBN 978-3-03719-146-0
DOI 10.4171/146
March 2015, 245 pages, hardcover, 16.5 x 23.5 cm.
68.00 Euro

Table of Contents

I. Class field theory: From Artin's course in Hamburg to Chevalley's "Éléments idéaux
Claude Chevalley's thesis on class field theory and his notion of "Éléments idéaux
Introduction
Letter from Claude Chevalley to Helmut Hasse, June 20, 1935
Letter from Helmut Hasse to Claude Chevalley, June 28, 1935
II. Creating a life: Emil Artin in America
Emigration, immigration and pre-remigration
Introduction
Letter from Solomon Lefschetz to Father John O'Hara, January 12, 1937
III. The collaboration of Emil Artin and George Whaples
The work of Artin and Whaples--A conceptual breakthrough in algebraic number theory
Introduction
George Whaples' application to the Institute for Advanced Study, School of Mathematics, Princeton, NJ, February 10, 1941
IV. Margaret Matchett: Artin's student at Indiana and her thesis
Margaret Matchett and her thesis "On the zeta function for ideles"
Introduction
Margaret Mathcett's doctoral dissertation "On the zeta function for ideles"
V. L-functions by James W. Cogdell
L-functions and non-abelian class field theory, from Artin to Langlands
VI. Automorphic L-functions by Robert P. Langlands
Letter from Robert Langlands to André Weil, January 1967
Funktorialität in der Theorie der automorphen Formen: Ihre Entdeckung und ihre Ziele
Einführung
Bibliography
Index